# Working on a form partial rendered through Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I am trying to create blog application in rails in which each post can be associated with many tags. A tag for a posts can be created or chosen from already existing tags.

**Post/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for([@topic, @post]) do |form| %>
  <label>Title </label><br/><%= form.text_field :title, required: true %><br/><br/>
  <label>Content </label> <br/> <%= form.text_area :content, required: true %><br/><br/>
  <%= form.collection_select(:tag_ids, Tag.all, :id, :name, {}, :multiple => true) %><br/><br/>
  <div id="tag">
    <%= link_to 'Create New Tag', new_tag_path, remote: true %>
  </div>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**Tag/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@tag, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.text_field :name%>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Tag/new.js.erb**

```
$("#tag").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial:'form')%>")
```

I rendered partial form while clicking on link 'Create New Path'. But when click on a link **'Create Tag**' and **'Create Post'** occurred it still creating a post but no tags. How can I create Tags? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have rendered form by but how values will get be set on the tag form?.

Instead, try to implement it using nested form gem.

Comment: @Rahul I have actually tried using nested attributes. I got an issue while editing the post. The tags that were associated with the post are displayed in the text_field for editing.

Comment: use bootstrap tags input  for  converting tags field to taggable field

https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/